# Install an app from Google Play on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to install Google Play app (such as for example Twitter) on Emulator? I tried to do it using browser in emulator, but it says "No devices".

**P.S. I don't have apk, I want to install app from Google Play.**

**P.S.S I have only emulator, no real device**

Comment: And if u need twitter.apk check this http://www.androiddrawer.com/1467/download-twitter-3-2-2-app-apk/#.UhSVMNKLCS8

Comment: hi, I also found that apk, but it is from 2012. I wonder how to install a new version

Comment: You have android phone? If yes then you can create backup of your Twitter Application. It will be created in .apk format. And then you can use that .apk on your emulator.

Comment: Check my updated answer below. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the Genymotion emulator. It allows to install apps from the store without a problem and it's really quick in comparison with standard emulator.

Comment: One of the requirements to install Google Play store on a Genymotion emulator is to download/install "ARM Translation Installer v1.1". This lead to a whole bunch of f*cking host sites that either a) show only ads and no download link b) warnings from chrome that the site is malicious.

Comment: Is the Genymotion service paid ? I mean do we have to pay something to use the emulator ?

Comment: I think non-profit/personal usage is ok. But for profit/company usage you have to pay. Check their page.

Answer (score 13):

This question is edited. This answer for those who have google play account.

If you want to download .apk files directly from Google Play. Check [this](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/). Apk downloader is a chrome extension which u can use to direct download .apk from google play on computer. After downloading that .apk

Start your emulator.

Start command prompt, and change your directory to the platform-tools folder of SDK directory.
Paste the APK file in the 'android-sdk\tools' or 'platform-tools' folder.
Then type the following command.

adb install yourapp.apk

Approach 2 - Download [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and use drag-drop approach on its emulator.

**Update** - Now you can drag drop .apk on your Andorid emulator.

Comment: He specifically stated he does not have an Android device. The link you posted requires an existing android device

Comment: @Patrick i don't think in any step that i mention. we need a device. If  think so . then let me know. think before downcaste answers.

Comment: You need a device in order to create a Google Play account. That was my scenario. Without ever having an account, there is no way you could ever have had a device. I would suggest updating your answer with those details

Comment: @patrick if you see the edited revisions. You can see that he said that he don't have real device or account at the last edit revision. And my answer is before that.

Comment: Fair enough. In the interest of others it's good to see you've updated your answer. I've removed my -1 :)

Comment: the link still works, but apkDownloader isn't maintained and the settings it asks for from chrome isn't available anymore. The answer from Bartekus gives a link that as of this comment posting, works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Gautam Jain as a comment under the first top suggestion discussion, the easiest way to download any app from Google PlayStore is to use: [apk.tools](https://apk.tools)

Once you have the .apk package you can simply drag&drop into your already running emulator.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the app on another device via the Play Store, then use a backup app to save the apk file to the SD card, move it from there to the emulator.

To install an apk in the emulator use something like

```
adb install <path>/Twitter.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this steps you will get there: http://www.android.pk/blog/general/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-emulator/

Comment: Please refrain from answering with external links only. While this might be a good reference, the origin might become unavailable and all that remains is dead weight on this question.